# How to check in which textfield cursor is present in java?

Tags: java, cursor, textfield

How will we find that the cursor is now in that text field?
I have two text fields in Java. I want to write text in a text field but before writing text I want to check which text field is selected. How can I check it?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [isFocusOwner()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isFocusOwner()):

```
if(textField.isFocusOwner()) {
    // the cursor is in the TextField
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, it does not give any input? Show us your code, please.